# Gradle test report shows test as failed if afterClass method fails

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, testng

Using

Java, Gradle, TestNG, Selenium

Is there a way to mark test as passed if @afterClass method fails but @Test method passes?

Gradle report marks the test as failure. I know in testng report the test is marked as a pass but afterClass method is reported as a failure separately.

Comment: So if I understand your problem correctly, when you run this test class from within an IDE, you are seeing `@Test` as passed and `@AfterClass` method as failed, but when you run via Gradle, you are seeing both `@Test` and `@AfterClass` as failed. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - if you want to just ignore the errors, you can use try-catch in `@AfterClass`:

```
@AfterClass
public void tearDown() {
    try {
        // code that throws exception
     } catch (Exception e) {
         //do nothing, or log error somewhere else
     }
}
```

Option 2 - turn off Gradle reports and just use Test NG's:

[build.gradle](https://jepombar.wordpress.com/2015/11/08/how-to-generate-testng-reports-with-gradle/)

```
test {
   useTestNG() {
     //report generation delegated to TestNG library:
     useDefaultListeners = true
   }

   //turn off Gradle's HTML report to avoid replacing the
   //reports generated by TestNG library:
   reports.html.enabled = false
 }
```

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for. I still want to display the exception in the report; just not as a failure but failed config like TestNG does.

Total Tests:
Failed Tests:
Skipped Tests: 
Failed Configurations:
Skipped Configurations:

Comment: Would it help if you tell gradle to just use the testng report instead?

Comment: Sure. Is there a way to report TestNG report instead?